# mysql safe read - update - write

Tags: mysql, go

I'm try to understand mysql lock record mechanic, this is show case in Golang
or here https://play.golang.org/p/2fGKEyh0Wl

it run 2 concurrent transactions, and they read-update on the same row
- the first transaction will try to lock the row, do something (sleep for 3 secs)
- the second then try to read-update on the same key

the test source code

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "github.com/satori/go.uuid"
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type Wallet struct {
    ID      string
    Balance int64
}

func main() {
    db, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", "root:abc123@tcp(mysql:3306)/test?parseTime=true")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    db.Exec(`CREATE TABLE test_wallet (
    id varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    balance bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    `)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    wID := uuid.NewV4().String()
    db.Exec("INSERT INTO test_wallet (id,balance) VALUES (?,?)", wID, 10)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        tx, err := db.Beginx()
        w1 := &Wallet{}
        err = db.Get(w1, "SELECT * FROM test_wallet WHERE id=? FOR UPDATE", wID) // read and lock the record
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        log.Printf("got %+v on r1\n", w1)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
        res, err := tx.Exec("UPDATE test_wallet SET balance=? WHERE id=?", w1.Balance+5, wID)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        n, err := res.RowsAffected()
        if n != 1 {
            log.Println("update not affected r1")
        }
        tx.Commit()
        log.Println("done on r1")
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second) // make sure go-routine lock `id` row

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        tx, err := db.Beginx()
        w2 := &Wallet{}
        err = db.Get(w2, "SELECT * FROM test_wallet WHERE id=? FOR UPDATE", wID)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        log.Printf("got %+v on r2\n", w2)
        res, err := tx.Exec("UPDATE test_wallet SET balance=? WHERE id=?", w2.Balance+7, wID)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        n, err := res.RowsAffected()
        if n != 1 {
            log.Println("update not affected r2")
        }
        tx.Commit()
        log.Println("done on r2")
    }()
    wg.Wait()
    w := &Wallet{}
    err = db.Get(w, "SELECT * FROM test_wallet WHERE id=?", wID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%+v\n", w)
}
```

result from my terminal

```
2016/10/01 09:57:00 got &{ID:aab7165c-4b3b-406d-b1d0-caf3f45f72be Balance:10} on r1
2016/10/01 09:57:01 got &{ID:aab7165c-4b3b-406d-b1d0-caf3f45f72be Balance:10} on r2
2016/10/01 09:57:01 done on r2
2016/10/01 09:57:03 done on r1
2016/10/01 09:57:03 &{ID:aab7165c-4b3b-406d-b1d0-caf3f45f72be Balance:15}
```

it seem the second routine has not been lock ???

Comment: This is a textbook example of not how to do balance updates because you're opening yourself up to race conditions and are attempting to mitigate that with locks, a mechanism that's bound to blow up in your face eventually. For anything involving money or money-like currency, **always** record individual debits and credits, **never** directly assign balances based on potentially out-of-date information. Do things like `SET balance=balance+?` instead, that is atomic and *will* work. Use **transactions**, not locks, to ensure atomicity and integrity.

Comment: yup, I have tried many solution, such as use *transactions* (I used it in above with `tx.Beginx`, and set mysql isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE` , but it still did not work as expect. My situation need to read the row outside, validate something, then update it with new value, it should make sure balance is not changed since last query, is there a way to archive this?

Comment: because I need some validation before decide to update `balance`, then I cannt use `SET balance=balance+?` ...

Comment: Validate all you want, but do use a *differential* update when you get around to doing it and always, always have a complete record of how the balance ended up that way. Every single alteration should be recorded as a row in some table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misused the transaction. The `db` **is not** in transaction, only `tx` is. So, the statements in first and second go routine which are

```
err = db.Get(w1, "SELECT * FROM test_wallet WHERE id=? FOR UPDATE", wID) // read and lock the record
err = db.Get(w2, "SELECT * FROM test_wallet WHERE id=? FOR UPDATE", wID)
```

will not lock the row, because `db` is not wrapped in transaction. You must use `tx` to execute the query, i.e.

```
err = tx.Get(w1, "SELECT * FROM test_wallet WHERE id=? FOR UPDATE", wID) // read and lock the record
err = tx.Get(w2, "SELECT * FROM test_wallet WHERE id=? FOR UPDATE", wID)
```

After modification, I got the following result:

```
2016/10/01 13:26:10 got &{ID:6ff45acd-701c-458f-a17f-84cc4e982c80 Balance:10} on r1
2016/10/01 13:26:14 done on r1
2016/10/01 13:26:14 got &{ID:6ff45acd-701c-458f-a17f-84cc4e982c80 Balance:15} on r2
2016/10/01 13:26:14 done on r2
2016/10/01 13:26:14 &{ID:6ff45acd-701c-458f-a17f-84cc4e982c80 Balance:22}
```

Comment: @secmark, please be sure to read and understand [this tutorial](http://go-database-sql.org/). Go approach to working with databases is different from those of other popular platforms, and you have to be aware of these differences.

Comment: thank you, thank you so so much!! Been banging my head around for this issue.